# Can Google crawl jquery mobile based pages?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to add mobile support for my website and I plan to implement it by serving different content based on the user agent. For mobile devices I want to use jQuery mobile to build the page. However, I'm concerned that since the mobile page version is built on the client side using javascript and ajax (as opposed to serving ready made HTML from the server) Google will not be able to crawl the mobile pages and those will get low page ranking.

Is my concern valid? is there any jQuery mobile best practice that takes into consideration SEO?

Comment: Now Google crawler runs `javaScript` on the page.

Comment: Your question is valid for crawlers that don't run JavaScript. Not sure which ones do and which ones don't though. For the ones that don't you can look into something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) which is meant to solve this problem by building the pages server side and then sending them to the client...

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be an issue, Google executes the page and crawls the resulting HTML after all of the code has run. You should follow SEO guidelines nonetheless, so have a look at this for starters:

http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf